# how to create multi column listbox widget in tkinter in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I want to show the data from a sqlite3 database into a list box with multiple columns. How can I configure a list box for multiple columns?
here's part of my code I want to show `serial` and `amount` into different columns but unable to do it. I'm new at this tell me how can I show the data from my database `customer`

```
def endofday():
   endoftheday = Tk()
   endoftheday.title("this is the final sheet")
   endoftheday.geometry("500x500+900+0")

   L1 = Listbox(endoftheday)
   L1.pack()

   c.execute('SELECT serial,amount FROM customer')
   L1.insert(END,c.fetchall())
```

Comment: This is pygybu `https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu`, it is a Rapid Application Development tool for tkinter. Saves lots of time

Comment: I've been using [this MultiListBox](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52266-multilistbox-tkinter-widget/) recipe in my tkinter applications for several years